# SQL Server 2008 - views taking too long when searching using more than 1 criteria

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, view

I've written a view in SQL Server 2008 which is being called by an aspx web page.

When I run it using one criteria (e.g. `Area = Townville`) it runs fine, but using two (e.g. `Area = Townville AND County = Townshire`) it takes ages, despite finding exactly the same results (ie Townville is located within Townshire).

Due to limits imposed by one of our clients, it has to work like this (with both an Area and County, even though the County isn't always necessarily necessary).

I don't think it's anything wrong with the view per se, as I've rewritten it to one that's more efficient and it's still taking ages.

EDIT - it's not actually the SQL (I think) as I tried it through the server with the relevant criteria. I think it must be the webpage that calls it. Here is where it is called, in c# -

```
        string MySQLString;
        MySQLString = "SELECT [L1_Name], [L2_Name], [L3_Name], [Spare1], [Spare2], [Spare3], [Spare4], [Spare5], [Operation_Name], [Team_Name], [LatestDate], [Issues], [Next], [Postcode], [Latitude], [Longitude], [OperationOrder], [FKID_Contract], [FKID_GeoType], [Geometry] FROM [vw_Report_Latest_v3_1] WHERE [FKID_Contract]=@Contract";
        if ((string)Session["TSAreaString"] != "") { MySQLString = MySQLString + " AND [L1_Name]=@PA1"; }
        if ((string)Session["TSSiteString"] != "") { MySQLString = MySQLString + " AND [L2_Name]=@PA2"; }
        if ((string)Session["TSFeatureString"] != "") { MySQLString = MySQLString + " AND [L3_Name]=@PA3"; }
        if ((string)Session["TSS1"] != "") { MySQLString = MySQLString + " AND [Spare1]=@S1"; }
        if ((string)Session["TSS2"] != "") { MySQLString = MySQLString + " AND [Spare2]=@S2"; }
        if ((string)Session["TSS3"] != "") { MySQLString = MySQLString + " AND [Spare3]=@S3"; }
        if ((string)Session["TSS4"] != "") { MySQLString = MySQLString + " AND [Spare4]=@S4"; }
        if ((string)Session["TSS5"] != "") { MySQLString = MySQLString + " AND [Spare5]=@S5"; }
        if ((string)Session["TSTaskString"] != "") { MySQLString = MySQLString + " AND [Operation_Name]=@PA4"; }
        if ((string)Session["TSTeamString"] != "") { MySQLString = MySQLString + " AND [Team_Name]=@Team"; }
        //finish
        MySQLString = MySQLString + " ORDER BY [OperationOrder], [L1_Name], [L2_Name], [L3_Name], [Operation_Name], [Team_Name]";
        try
        {
            Conn.Open();
            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(MySQLString, Conn);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contract", Convert.ToInt32(invCID.Text));
            if (lblPA1.Text != "All") { Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PA1", (string)Session["TSAreaString"]); }
            if (lblPA2.Text != "All") { Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PA2", (string)Session["TSSiteString"]); }
            if (lblPA3.Text != "All") { Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PA3", (string)Session["TSFeatureString"]); }
            if (lblS1V.Text != "All") { Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S1", (string)Session["TSS1"]); }
            if (lblS2V.Text != "All") { Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S2", (string)Session["TSS2"]); }
            if (lblS3V.Text != "All") { Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S3", (string)Session["TSS3"]); }
            if (lblS4V.Text != "All") { Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S4", (string)Session["TSS4"]); }
            if (lblS5V.Text != "All") { Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S5", (string)Session["TSS5"]); }
            if (lblPA4.Text != "All") { Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PA4", (string)Session["TSTaskString"]); }
            if (lblTeam.Text != "All") { Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team", (string)Session["TSTeamString"]); }
            SqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
            Cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MyAdapter.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
            Session["MyTable"] = dt;
            GridView1.DataSource = Session["MyTable"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Conn != null) { Conn.Close(); }
        }
```

So we create our MySQLString, which addresses the vw_Report_Latest_v3_1 view. Criteria are added depending on what we need.

In my specific example, Session["TSAreaString"] is set to a specific town, which is fine and loads up in about 2 seconds (it's a big town). This relates to L1_Name.

However, Session["TSS3"], which in our demo case is our County, is the one that causes this to slow down to a crawl. This relates to Spare3.

Again, in the view itself in SQL Server 2008, this doesn't seem to be a problem. But it does seem to be a problem on the page that executes it.

Comment: Have you viewed the Execution Plan in SSMS? This may give you a clue as to why the second criteria slows everything down.

Comment: Never come across that before. I'll have a look for it.

Comment: Did you ever execute the `select` on view from SSMS? Is it slow there are as well?

Comment: I made a mistake with the original question. It seems to be working fine in SQL, but not when I run it on the webpage. It's called by the c# code above.